# Qt 4.8 - Showing “loading” animation while updating the QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt4, qgraphicsscene

I’m using Qt 4.8.

I have a big QGraphicsScene to update (it takes 3 secs to append the new QGraphicsObjects).
I would like to show the user that the update is in progress.
In particular I thought about showing a loading wheel on screen and than remove it when the update ends.

The problem here is that I should make the wheel visible and then not visible in the 
same thread of the scene update. This because:

- It is not allowed to edit graphic properties outside the gui thread.
- I cannot move the computation in a “worker thread” since it involves graphics.

This results in the wheel not showing at all, since when the view is updated the wheel
has been already set visible and then not visible again:

```
showWheel();
/*... big computation involving graphics ...*/
hideWheel();
/*... here GUI is updated, thus the wheel doesn't show up...*/
```

Is there anything I can do?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you please show me how you implemented the showWheel() animation?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have some event triggering the computation.  Instead of using it to trigger the computation, use it to trigger a `scheduleComputation()`slot.  The `scheduleComputation` slot can call `showWheel()` and then schedule the `doComputation()` slot for the end of the next event queue, after which it will return.  This will allow the event loop to run and show your wheel, then perform computation.  When computation is over, you can call `hideWheel()` and return to the event loop.

Something like this:

```
void scheduleComputation()
{
    computeScheduler = new QTimer(this);
    computeScheduler->setInterval(0);
    connect(computeScheduler,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(doComputation()));
    showWheel();
}

void doComputation()
{
    //...Computation Here...
    hideWheel();
}
```

It is also a good idea to keep from blocking the UI thread for long periods of time.  This can be done by splitting your long running code into smaller pieces that can be triggered by a timer.

Answer (score 0):

At regular intervals in the "big computation" you can let the event handler run for a little while.